# Record added two into the sqlserverdatabase using c#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am creating a simple inventory system using c#. sales product table data added success.but sales table data added twice i don't know why. what i tried so far i attached below. i attached the sales table below record added twice

**sales table**

```
id  subtoal pay      bal
27  900.00  1000.00 100.00
28  900.00  1000.00 100.00




 string bal = txtBal.Text;
                string sub = txtSub.Text;
                string pay = textBox1.Text;
                sql = "insert into sales(subtoal,pay,bal) values(@subtoal,@pay,@bal); select @@identity;";
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtoal", sub);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay", pay);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bal", bal);
                int lastinsertID = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());               
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string proddname;
                int price;
                int qty;
                int tot;


                for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    proddname = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                     price = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                     qty = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString());

                     int total = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString());


                     sql1 = "insert into sales_product(sales_id,prodname,price,qty,total) values(@sales_id,@prodname,@price,@qty,@total)";

                     cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
                     cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sales_id", lastinsertID);
                     cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodname", proddname);
                     cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
                     cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qty);
                     cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);
                     cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

                MessageBox.Show("Record Addddedddd");

                con.Close();
```

Comment: You're executing the statement twice: `int lastinsertID = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());` followed by `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: thanks sir it is working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Larnu's commment you were executing the query twice. In this case you should only use the ExecuteScalar() version to retrieve the last inserted id for later use

I also wanted to point out that the design intent is to initialize the parameters collection once, then re use it many times, executing each time. You should also put `using` statements to make your commands, more like this, and you should probably get into the habit of using SCOPE_IDENTITY() rather than @@identity:

```
        using(var con = new SqlConnection(...)){
            con.Open();

            string bal = txtBal.Text;
            string sub = txtSub.Text;
            string pay = textBox1.Text;
            sql = "insert into sales(subtoal,pay,bal) values(@subtoal,@pay,@bal); select scope_identity();";

            int lastinsertId = 0;
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con){
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtoal", sub);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay", pay);
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bal", bal);
              lastinsertID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();               
            }

            string proddname = "";
            int price = 0;
            int qty = 0;
            int tot = 0;

            sql1 = "insert into sales_product(sales_id,prodname,price,qty,total) values(@sales_id,@prodname,@price,@qty,@total)";
            using(var cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con)){
              cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sales_id", lastinsertID);
              cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodname", proddname);
              cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
              cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qty);
              cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);

              for (int row = 0; row < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; row++)
              {
                 proddname = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                 price = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                 qty = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[2].Value.ToString());

                 int total = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[3].Value.ToString());

                 cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
                 cmd1.Parameters["@sales_id"].Value = lastinsertID;
                 cmd1.Parameters["@prodname"].Value = proddname;
                 cmd1.Parameters["@price"].Value = price;
                 cmd1.Parameters["@qty"].Value = qty;
                 cmd1.Parameters["@total"].Value = total;
                 cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
            } //end using sqlcommand

         }//end using sqlconnection - it will close as a result

         MessageBox.Show("Record Addddedddd");
```

And then I also wanted to point out that your life could get a lot easier if you use Dapper. With dapper the code would look more like:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
  sql = "insert into sales(subtoal,pay,bal) values(@subtoal,@pay,@bal); select scope_identity();";
  var lastInsertId = connection.Query<int>(sql, new { 
     subtoal = txtSub.Text,
     pay = textBox1.Text,
     bal = txtBal.Text
   }
  ).Single();

  foreach(...)
}
```

It does all the parameter jiggling for you, runs the query, manages the connection  ,returns a type casted int etc

Also if your datagridview is based on a DataTable (and even better a strongly typed datatable) you can use it in your foreach. Here's what a strongly typed table would look like:

```
using(...){
  foreach(var ro in SalesProductTable){

    sql = "insert into sales_product(sales_id,prodname,price,qty,total) values(@sales_id,@prodname,@price,@qty,@total)";
    dapperConnection.Execute(sql, new { ro.sales_id, ro.prodname, ro.price, ro.qty, ro.total });
  }
```

Yep, that's it; just 4 lines of code, and it's easier if your @param names match  your column names in your strongly typed table.

I think you might even just  be able to get Dapper to do the looping too, by passing the datatable in, so long as the rows have properties that are the same as the parameters in the query:

```
using(...){
    sql = "insert into sales_product(sales_id,prodname,price,qty,total) values(@sales_id,@prodname,@price,@qty,@total)";
    dapperConnection.Execute(sql, salesProductTable);
}
```

take a look - http://dapper-tutorial.net